# Import() and import * not working together. Node and Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm working on an app with this general setup:

babel-node -> Express server -> Webpack middleware -> React

I'm trying to implement code-splitting with import(). This is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "loose": true,
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      "react-hot-loader/babel",
      "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
      "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack",
      "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy",
      "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties",
      "react-intl",
      {
        "messagesDir": "./build/messages",
        "enforceDescriptions": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Some of the Node's code is using `import * from *`, so if I remove **"modules": false** everything is working properly, but Webpack fails because he can't interpret **import()**. Otherwise node fails because doesn't understand **import ***. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `dynamic-import-webpack` since webpack v2 comes with it now.

It looks like you do have `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` installed. Try including it in your `.babelrc` like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"] 
}
```